# typescript filter data inside nested children

Tags: typescript

I have data looks like this

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Concerts",
    "events": [],
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1207,
            "name": "Rock and Pop",
            "events": [],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 429,
                    "name": "Backstreet Boys",
                    "children": [],
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "id": 4422829,
                            "name": "Backstreet Boys",
                            "venueName": "Freedom Mortgage Pavilion",
                            "city": "Camden",
                            "price": 23,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 131162.390908814,
                            "date": "Jul 16 2020"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4422826,
                            "name": "Backstreet Boys",
                            "venueName": "Xfinity Theatre",
                            "city": "Hartford",
                            "price": 20,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 160356.993027791,
                            "date": "Jul 17 2022"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 150029205,
                            "name": "Backstreet Boys",
                            "date": "Jul 24 2022",
                            "venueName": "Bethel Woods Center for the Arts",
                            "city": "Bethel",
                            "price": 69,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 122298.256317016
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Justin Bieber",
                    "id": 450948,
                    "children": [],
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "id": 8621837,
                            "name": "Justin Bieber",
                            "date": "Jul 17 2022",
                            "venueName": "The OVO Hydro (formerly The SSE Hydro)",
                            "city": "Glasgow",
                            "price": 97,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 5181466.9468135
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 8621843,
                            "name": "Justin Bieber",
                            "date": "Jul 24 2022",
                            "venueName": "The O2",
                            "city": "London",
                            "price": 138,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 5581760.89658226
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 8621842,
                            "name": "Justin Bieber",
                            "date": "Jul 24 2022",
                            "venueName": "The O2",
                            "city": "London",
                            "price": 110,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 5581760.89658226
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Elton John",
                    "id": 43088,
                    "children": [],
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "id": 6216095,
                            "name": "Elton John",
                            "date": "Jul 30 2022",
                            "venueName": "Progressive Field",
                            "city": "Cleveland",
                            "price": 133,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 643919.392660771
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 6222261,
                            "name": "Elton John",
                            "dayOfWeek": "Fri",
                            "date": "Aug 05 2022",
                            "venueName": "Soldier Field",
                            "city": "Chicago",
                            "price": 91,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 1138316.92169974
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 6217165,
                            "name": "Elton John",
                            "date": "Sep 07 2022",
                            "venueName": "Rogers Centre",
                            "city": "Chicago",
                            "price": 108,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 1138316.92169974
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1026,
            "name": "Rap/Hip-Hop/Reggae",
            "events": [],
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Rage Against the Machine",
                    "id": 100920451,
                    "children": [],
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "id": 4423330,
                            "name": "Rage Against the Machine",
                            "date": "Aug 09 2022",
                            "venueName": "Madison Square Garden",
                            "city": "New York",
                            "price": 103,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 5571576.14652457
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4430490,
                            "name": "Rage Against The Machine with Run The Jewels",
                            "url": "/rage-against-the-machine-new-york-tickets-8-11-2022/event/104589398/",
                            "date": "Aug 11 2022",
                            "venueName": "Madison Square Garden",
                            "city": "New York",
                            "price": 95,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 5571576.14652457
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4922928,
                            "name": "Rage Against The Machine & Run The Jewels",
                            "date": "Aug 12 2022",
                            "venueName": "Madison Square Garden",
                            "city": "New York",
                            "price": 160,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 5571576.14652457
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daddy Yankee",
                    "id": 66913,
                    "children": [],
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "id": 10278327,
                            "name": "Daddy Yankee",
                            "date": "Aug 12 2022",
                            "venueName": "SAP Center",
                            "city": "San Jose",
                            "price": 130,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 8640632.67448427
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 10275468,
                            "name": "Daddy Yankee",
                            "date": "Aug 13 2022",
                            "venueName": "The Kia Forum",
                            "city": "Inglewood",
                            "price": 37,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 8776920.13120377
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 10380132,
                            "name": "Daddy Yankee",
                            "date": "Aug 15 2022",
                            "venueName": "The Kia Forum",
                            "city": "Inglewood",
                            "price": 16,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 8776920.13120377
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1027,
            "name": "R&B/Urban Soul",
            "events": [],
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Chris Brown",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 106817,
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "id": 150100779,
                            "name": "Chris Brown & Lil Baby",
                            "date": "Aug 12 2022",
                            "venueName": "iTHINK Financial Amphitheatre",
                            "city": "West Palm Beach",
                            "price": 19,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 7057650.78884398
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 150096789,
                            "name": "Chris Brown & Lil Baby",
                            "date": "Aug 13 2022",
                            "venueName": "MidFlorida Credit Union Amphitheatre at the Florida State Fairgrounds",
                            "city": "Tampa",
                            "price": 28,
                            "distanceFromVenue": 7099615.41662152
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to create a function filter nested events by dynamic keys
they search keys will be the city and the price
I have two inputs trigger `handleOnChange` once change happens

```
const filterBy = (
    data: EventRootObject | undefined,
    name: string,
    value: string
  ): EventRootObject | undefined => {
    if (data) {
      const filteredEvent = data.events.filter((event: EventType) =>
        event[name].match(value)
      );
      data.events = filteredEvent;

      const childs = data.children?.map((child: any) => {
        return filterBy(child, name, value);
      });
      data.children = childs;

      return data;
    }
  };

const handleOnChange = (e: any) => {
    const result = filterBy(orignialEventsList, e.target.name, e.target.value);
    console.log('result ', result);
    setEventList(result);
  };
```

the types

```
export interface EventType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  venueName: string;
  city: string;
  price: number;
  distanceFromVenue: number;
  date: string;
  dayOfWeek: string;
  url: string;
}

export interface EventRootObject {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  events: EventType[] | [];
  children: any[];
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you encounter? Is it the error at `event[name].match(value)`? And if so, would this approach work for you? https://tsplay.dev/WYZ6xw

Comment: Thanks for the reply your answer very helpful, but is my filter way is sufficient to go over all child and filter the events or could be better